# How to keep the Jquery Dialog open?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui-dialog

A Dialog is opened after clicking an icon from the `1.cshtml` page. If I click another link in the `1.cshtml` page, the Dialog disappear. How to **keep it open**?

`1.cshtml` code related to name-dialog

```
$('#name-dialog').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 500,
    resizable: false,
    title: 'Name',
    modal: false,
    buttons: {
        "Close": function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Setting `modal` to true would mean you can't click any of the other links on the page.  Would that not be good enough?

Comment: I purposely made modal to false since I want to navigate pages clicking on `1.cshtml` page with the dialog stay open.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stay on the same page all links inside the dialog should be handled by AJAX. You could use an `Ajax.ActionLink` instead of an `Html.ActionLink`. This way when clicking on some anchor, an AJAX request will be sent and the browser will stay on the current page. Same stands true if you have any HTML forms.

Comment: I want that modal alone to be keep open and not want to want to stay on the same page, but modal is disappearing once after clicking on any other link when navigating to some page.

Comment: It's normal that the modal is being closed. You are redirected away from the current page. The modal is something created with javascript that ceases to exist once you leave the page. If you want to have a modal on the target page you will have to once again use javascript on this target page to open it. But you probably just want to perform the action using AJAX without leaving the page.